# how to obfuscate google keys in Android using ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, reverse-engineering, obfuscation, api-key

I have been searching this solution everywhere but I cannot make it work yet. My google API key is stored in a string inside res folder, I have enabled proguard in my project, set the properties, later generating the APK (tried both unsigned and signed) but still being able to do reverse engineering to my generated APK to get the Google Key again (using Android Studio or even http://www.javadecompilers.com/apktool).

Google recommends in their documentation to store API keys in the res folder to use it in the manifest, but never explains how to help with reverse-engineering security on that key.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` has this piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.proyecto.cutcsa.cutcsa" >
    ...

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

        ...

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_key" />

    ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My `build.gradle` has the next:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.proyecto.cutcsa.cutcsa"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
}
```

And my `proguard-rules.pro
    -optimizationpasses 5

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames    

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

-dontpreverify

-verbose

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-dontwarn java.awt.**

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Can somebody help me with this problem? I will really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Speech/app/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/android/speech/AccessTokenLoader.java#L68  as noted your design is not good.  You need to host a process that will provide a token in a response as noted in the docs.

Comment: @Robert Rowntree thank you for your answer. Why do you say that my design is not good? Google suggests to work with their API keys this way: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start 
Moreover, how does the sample that you posted in your comment work? How do I call it? How do I use it? Kind regards!

Comment: If you get the reason for the warning issued by google in the code-link you are good. A note on the warning ....  mobile client that requests an access Token from a server( SECURE) is different from a client that just stores either the api-key or , as per the example, stores the entire CREDENTIAL. Even with obfuscation, a KEY in ./res/raw or a CREDENTIAL in ./res/raw is not the best security.

Comment: That's something I do not understand. How does Google offer solutions of how to use their APIS but never help the developers regarding security of them? If Google explains examples storing the key in the res folder (or in the Manifest), and they dont show any other way to do so, there should be a way to create secure applications using this approach. Nevertheless, I tried to think and search a way to store the Google API keys in my server but I cannot figure out how to "give" this key to my maps

Comment: @Robert Rowntree just in case, I am not saving the keys in the res/raw. I'm saving them in the res/values

Comment: google is a friend .... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances  and off that rootLink, also 2 anchors : #clientlib     #applications    for details on the distinction between requesting a Token  from a hosted service account,  VERSUS trying to hide on the client,  the actual KEY , CREDENTIAL. @T.Neidhart has good advice . just recognize that you have (KEYS, CREDENTIALS) on the client.

Answer (score 0):

To obfuscate string values (like API keys) you could take a look at [DexGuard](http://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard) which is the commercial variant of ProGuard. It supports inlining of resource values and encryption of strings to make it much more difficult to reverse-engineer sensitive data from an apk.